# Image opacity doesn't increase in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make an image gradually emerge using opacity property, only to find that its opacity only increases 0.1 instead of 1. It seems that it only increases one time, but I set condition that it continue to increase until opacity reaches 1.

So I use another same image, whose opacity is 1. Then decrease opacity until opacity reaches 0. However, it finally disappears as expected.

It turns out that opacity can only change from 1 to 0, but can't change from 0 to 1?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<img class="view1" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/10/21/54/performers-5644247__480.jpg">
<img class="view2" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/10/21/54/performers-5644247__480.jpg">
<script>
    let myView = document.querySelector('.view1');
    myView.style.opacity = 1;
    function changeOpacity() {
        myView.style.opacity -= 0.01;
        if (myView.style.opacity <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }
    let timer = setInterval(changeOpacity, 10);

    let secondView = document.querySelector('.view2');
    secondView.style.opacity = 0;
    function changeAnotherOpacity() {
        secondView.style.opacity += 0.1;
        if (secondView.style.opacity >= 1) {
            clearInterval(anotherTimer);
        }
    }
    let anotherTimer = setInterval(changeAnotherOpacity, 10);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

IDE might warn that opacity is a string, but it doesn't matter. The result is same even if write `myView.style.opacity = "1"`

Comment: `.style.opacity` is a string ... inspect the element (developer tools or console.log the result) and you'll see what I mean

Comment: `parseFloat(myView.style.opacity)` before doing math operations on that value

Comment: also, you can achieve far smoother animation using CSS

Comment: yeah, opacity is a string. It turns out that if I write `secondView.style.opacity = parseFloat(secondView.style.opacity) + 0.1 + ""`, opacity works by changing from 0 to 1. But I'm still wondering why the first image's opacity can subtract 0.01 as a string, while second image's opacity can't add 0.1 as a string.

Comment: `-` coerces strings to numbers ... `+` coerces numbers to strings ... javascript was written in 10 days :p

Comment: I've added an answer explaining the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue lies within the `+=` and `-=` operators to Set the value. As `-=` only applies for Mathematical operations, `+=` can also concatenate strings. In the first the String gets converted to a Number to use the `-=` operator, therefore reducing the number value by 0.1 works as expected. But the `+=` operator will concatenate the value as a String, because the value of `.style.opacity` is a String and therefore concatenating the 0.1 as a String resulting in "00.1", which is somewhat weird but will be corrected to "0.1". But the 2nd Iteration would resolve in "0.10.1" as the new value, which cant be corrected or even converted to a valid Number.

Hence you should adjust your code for compensating this behaviour:

```js
function changeAnotherOpacity() {
  secondView.style.opacity = Number(secondView.style.opacity) + 0.1;
  if (secondView.style.opacity >= 1) {
    clearInterval(anotherTimer);
  }
}
```

Comment: The former I understand. `+=` can concatenate strings while `-=` can't. I mean no offence, but the last sentence you mention may be wrong. In fact, "00.1" is same with `0.1` because the image is almost disappearing but can still be seen, from which we can judge opacity indeed increases 0.1. In the second plus operation, `"0.1" + "0.1" = "0.10.1"`, so that css can't judge what it is, so opacity remain the same level.

Comment: Yes, you're right.